# PHP Convert separate day,month and year to date

Tags: php, date

I looked in many threads regarding this issue but still can't get to the bottom of this one. Here is my code:

```
$birthdate_ts = strtotime("$year-$num_month-$day");
$birthdate = date("d/m/Y",$birthdate_ts);
```

Where $day $num_month and $year are numbers (example 1 10 1990).
The result I'm getting is 1/1/1970 every time. I also tried different variations for the "strtotime()" input and still nothing.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: If anyone got good explanation on strtotime and date methods that would be great since the manual is not helping me unfortunately.

Comment: Is should work, make a dump of `"$year-$num_month-$day"` to see if the date string is ok.

Comment: found out it was a problem with my month input. sorry for the trouble and thank you all guys.

Comment: I told you. :) Always verify your input string, moreover when using dynamic var in string.

Comment: @COil thanks man. sometimes I need you experts to tell me my code is good and the input is bad. I am still a n00b :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parse format is "d/m/y" and your format you are creating is "Y-m-d".  They need to match.  Try this:

```
$birthdate_ts=strtotime("$year-$num_month-$day");
$birthdate=date("Y-m-d",$birthdate_ts);
```

Comment: I tried this one:
        $birthdate_ts=strtotime("$day/$num_month/$year");
        $birthdate=date("d/m/Y",$birthdate_ts);
because thats how my DB format for dates is. still not working.

Comment: found out it was a problem with my month input. sorry for the trouble and thank you all guys.